# Android Async interface to get data obtained fron json request

Tags: android

i am new to Android,here is class Question bank returns list of json obj received from an api
ArrayAsyncResponse in interface containing only one method process complete ,i readed that http request is asynchronous but unable to relate

Question is model class 
case 1) when there is no ArrayAsyncResponse interface exist and i return the list to main activity and print it it shows empty list but when i make call to callback.processComplete() and then return list followed by printing ,it shows data 
case2 )if i pass null in this function callback.processComplete() then again returned list is empty
so what basically Interface is helping us

public class QuestionBank {
    ArrayList questionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curiousily/simple-quiz/master/script/statements-data.json";

```
public List<Question> getQuestions(final AnswerListAsyncResponse callBack) {

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            (JSONArray) null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            Question question = new Question();
                            question.setAnswer(response.getJSONArray(i).get(0).toString());
                            question.setAnswerTrue(response.getJSONArray(i).getBoolean(1));



                            //Add question objects to list
                            questionArrayList.add(question);
                            //Log.d("Hello", "onResponse: " + question.getAnswer());


                           // Log.d("JSON", "onResponse: " + response.getJSONArray(i).get(0));
                            //Log.d("JSON2", "onResponse: " + response.getJSONArray(i).getBoolean(1));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    if (null != callBack) callBack.processFinished(questionArrayList);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);


    return questionArrayList;

}
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private QuestionBank questionBank;
List<Question> questionList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    questionBank=new QuestionBank();
    questionList=questionBank.getQuestions(new AnswerListAsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinished(ArrayList<Question> questionsArrayList) {//this function triggers when response is received from api
            Log.d("inside", "processFinished: "+questionsArrayList);
        }
    });
    Log.d("sync response", "questionLIst: "+questionList);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't write this in comment, but I think I can help you.

I don't understand well your question. but I think you need to get a Listener of the async in your class activity.

You can do that with EventBus, like this : https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: ya its a good option ,but i m curious to understand internal working